# Java installation (or apt-get?) problem

Tags: installation, java

Two weeks ago I made several successful Java installations without any problem following link

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-ubuntu-12-04.html

But today I faced a problem. I was running standard apt-get update command, and faced warning message:

```
root@myname:~# add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK6 / JDK7 / JDK8). There are no actual Java files in this PPA. More info: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
```

After pressing [ENTER], download of packages where stuck on ~90%.

Message that confused me was There are no actual Java files in this PPA.

Does it means that PPA has been changed in last few days?

Can you help me how to solve this problem and install Java as I did two weeks ago?

Comment: have you told ubuntugeek about this problem? it's their ppa.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

Answer (score 2):

The reason that there are technically no Java files in the PPA is because of legal reasons; the PPA is an "Oracle JDK *Installer*".  Java isn't freely redistributable, so the PPA makes you agree to the license and then downloads it from Java to head off any potential legal conflicts.  The PPA has always been this way.

Answer (score 2):

I cant help you install java with that ppa. But I can explain why there is no java files in the ppa. Its because Sun(now Oracle) changed their license. They no longer allow java to be downloaded from third party servers. The ppa is distributing a script/program that downloads and installs java for you.

To manually install java use this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)